# how to add progress bar on multiple sql injection

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, foreach, transactions

I've been trying to add progress bar on my injection transaction but had no success. I need to show how much percent it has been while inserting data on my tables. I have multiple tables and multiple inserts. I also have a loop insert on a multiple table as shown at the foreach statement using listview data. When I try to insert with 100 records from the listview, my computer begins to lag and there's no telling when it will be finished.

Can anybody show me how to do it and how to link the backgroundworker to the progress bar.

I also need to check the progress of saveEdit()-function with multiple update on multiple tables and saveDelete() -function with multiple delete on multiple tables

I think it will be overkill if I put my saveAdd() code in the backgroundWorkerDoWork function since I also need to put saveEdit() and saveDelete() functions which has a many lines of code.

By the way I am using fbconnection which is almost the same with sqlconnection functionality.

```
private void saveAdd()
    {
        backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(); // loading bar 

        DBconnection dbConString = new DBconnection(); //initialize connectDB with connection string
        FbConnection dbConnect = new FbConnection(dbConString.getConnectionString()); // connect to database using connectdb
        dbConnect.Open(); // open the connection
        FbTransaction transaction = dbConnect.BeginTransaction(); // instantiate transaction

        backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(10);// loading bar not working

        try
        {
            FbCommand myCommand1 = new FbCommand(getQuerryStrings("insEquipMstDtl"), dbConnect, transaction); //stantiate sql command
            myCommand1.Parameters.Add("equipmentid", SqlDbType.BigInt).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            myCommand1.ExecuteScalar();// insert into tbl_equipmst or equipmaster
            string strDtlequipmentid = myCommand1.Parameters["equipmentid"].Value.ToString();
            //MessageBox.Show(strDtlequipmentid);

            backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(15);// loading bar not working

            FbCommand myCommand2 = new FbCommand(getQuerryStrings("insEquipTransaction", strDtlequipmentid), dbConnect, transaction); //stantiate sql command
            myCommand2.Parameters.Add("EQUIPTRANSID", SqlDbType.BigInt).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            myCommand2.ExecuteScalar(); // inserts transaction details
            string strDtlequiptransid = myCommand2.Parameters["EQUIPTRANSID"].Value.ToString();

            backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(20);// loading bar  not working

            FbCommand myCommand3 = new FbCommand(getQuerryStrings("insEquipWarServDtl", strDtlequipmentid, strDtlequiptransid), dbConnect, transaction); //stantiate sql command
            myCommand3.ExecuteNonQuery(); // inserts service warranty in details

            backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(25);// loading bar not working

            FbCommand myCommand4 = new FbCommand(getQuerryStrings("insEquipWarProdDtl", strDtlequipmentid, strDtlequiptransid), dbConnect, transaction); //stantiate sql command
            myCommand4.ExecuteNonQuery(); // inserts product warranty in details

            backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(30);// loading bar  not working

            FbCommand myCommand5 = new FbCommand(getQuerryStrings("insEquipStatDtl", strDtlequipmentid, strDtlequiptransid), dbConnect, transaction); //stantiate sql command
            myCommand5.ExecuteNonQuery(); // inserts equipmtn status

            backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(35);// loading bar  not working

            FbCommand myCommand6 = new FbCommand(getQuerryStrings("insEquipLocationDtl", strDtlequipmentid, strDtlequiptransid), dbConnect, transaction); //stantiate sql command
            myCommand6.ExecuteNonQuery(); // inserts location

            backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(40);// loading bar  not working


            if (chkParts.Checked == true)
            {
                if (lvwPartsList.Items.Count !=0 )
                {


                    foreach (ListViewItem item in lvwPartsList.Items)
                    {
                        FbCommand myCommand7 = new FbCommand(getPartsQuerryStrings("insEquipMstPart", strDtlequipmentid, item), dbConnect, transaction); //stantiate sql command
                        myCommand7.Parameters.Add("equipmentid", SqlDbType.BigInt).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                        myCommand7.ExecuteScalar();// parts insert into tbl_equipmst or equipmaster 
                        string strPartsequipmentid = myCommand7.Parameters["equipmentid"].Value.ToString();

                        FbCommand myCommand8 = new FbCommand(getPartsQuerryStrings("insEquipTransactionPart", strPartsequipmentid), dbConnect, transaction); //stantiate sql command
                        myCommand8.Parameters.Add("EQUIPTRANSID", SqlDbType.BigInt).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                        myCommand8.ExecuteScalar(); // inserts transaction details - parts
                        string strPartequiptransid = myCommand8.Parameters["EQUIPTRANSID"].Value.ToString();

                        FbCommand myCommand9 = new FbCommand(getPartsQuerryStrings("insEquipWarServPart", strPartsequipmentid, strPartequiptransid,item), dbConnect, transaction); //stantiate sql command
                        myCommand9.ExecuteNonQuery(); // inserts service warranty in details - parts

                        FbCommand myCommand10 = new FbCommand(getPartsQuerryStrings("insEquipWarProdPart", strPartsequipmentid, strPartequiptransid, item), dbConnect, transaction); //stantiate sql command
                        myCommand10.ExecuteNonQuery(); // inserts product warranty in details - parts

                        FbCommand myCommand11 = new FbCommand(getPartsQuerryStrings("insEquipStatPart", strPartsequipmentid, strPartequiptransid, item), dbConnect, transaction); //stantiate sql command
                        myCommand11.ExecuteNonQuery(); // inserts equipmtn status - parts

                        FbCommand myCommand12 = new FbCommand(getPartsQuerryStrings("insEquipLocationPart", strPartsequipmentid, strPartequiptransid, item), dbConnect, transaction); //stantiate sql command
                        myCommand12.ExecuteNonQuery(); // inserts equipmtn location - parts

                    }          
                }

            }
            transaction.Commit();

            MessageBox.Show("Successful");
            frmNormalMode();

        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            transaction.Rollback();
            MessageBox.Show("No Update has been made. Error (" +
                x.Message + ")");
        }
        finally
        {
            dbConnect.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're using `BackgroundWorker` wrongly. You need to do the time consuming work in `DoWork` event handler. Right now your code runs in calling thread, not the worker thread. Refer [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: I tried to use that kind of backgroundworker but the problem is I don't have the idea how to implement it if I have multiple functions. That specific function is one of them. I have function for multiple insert(ADD), Multiple update(edit) and multiple delete.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `BackgroundWorker` in a wrong way. As a first step, make the following changes to your code. At the point where you create your `BackgroundWorker`, set `backgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress` to True (or if you use the control, set it to true in the Properties window).
Next, implement the `DoWork` event. It should contain your save code. Again, you can use the event `DoWork` in the Properties window. Now it should look like this (note I used the control from the Toolbox window, so I have the backgroundworker as a control on my form):

```
private bool arePartsChecked;

private List<string> partsList = new List<string>();

private void saveAdd()
{
    arePartsChecked = chkParts.Checked; 
    partsList.Clear();
    foreach (ListViewItem item in lvwPartsList.Items)
      partsList.Add(item.Text);
    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(); // loading bar
    // remove saving code, move it to DoWork event
}

private void backgroundWorkerDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    DBconnection dbConString = new DBconnection();
    FbConnection dbConnect = new FbConnection(dbConString.getConnectionString()); 
    // part of your code ......
    if ((arePartsChecked) && (partsList.Count > 0))
    {
        foreach (itemList partsList)
        {
            FbCommand myCommand7 = new FbCommand(getPartsQuerryStrings("insEquipMstPart",
              strDtlequipmentid, item), dbConnect, transaction); //stantiate sql command AND note: item is now a string...!!
            // etc.
        }
        // ...
    } 
    finally
    {
        dbConnect.Close();
    }
}
```

Now implement the private void `ProgressChanged` event. It should contain code like:

```
private void backgroundWorkerProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}
```

Where progressBar is your progress bar on the form.

Comment: Ok sir. I'll try that. the thing is I have another function with saveEdit()-multiple update and saveDelete()-multiple delete. how can I use the backgroundWorkerDoWork to the other save functions when the add is using it? thx

Comment: You could use 3 background workers, one that handles Add, one handling Edit (or Update) and one Delete. The `DoWork` events have to be implemented differently (you have already Add, but the others have to implement the Edit and Delete actions). But the ProgressChanged events can be the same (at least, I'm expecting that because you want to update the value of the `ProgressBar`).

Comment: I'll try that method. I was expecting like backgroundWorkerDoWork+ handler something. Not really familiar with handlers since I am just an amateur in c#

Comment: If you tell how you have added the `BackgroundWorkers` I can change the code to make it more clear. Did you use declaration in your code (i.e., `BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();` or have you drag/dropped a `BackgroundWorker` control from the Toolbox on your form?

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm just a little bit confused. I drag the background worker from the panel to the winform and trying to use as a handler. Is that a wrong method? hmmm never the less I'll try your code when I reach home.

Comment: I tried your code and an error has occurred. "Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'lvwlistPart' accessed from a thread other than thread it was created on". I think there is an incompatibility with my listview code and with the do work. I think it is in the foreach Part

Comment: You cannot reference `Form` controls in a code part that is processed by a different thread. Code that is executed within `backgroundWorker.DoWork` cannot access lvwPartsList (and chkParts is also a suspect). What you could do is just before executing `backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();` is store the necessary in private fields, and use them in the `DoWork` part. I will add an example for the checkbox; I hope you can change it for the listview items.

Comment: Ahh. I see. I'll try to implement it that way.

Comment: I'm sorry if I can't check this for my answer just yet. I'm still working on the project base code at the same time doing technical work. I will integrate and check it. maybe after 2 days. thx